# So long, and thanks for all the fish

Tags: discussion, deleted-account

Goodbye, y'all.  I've been diagnosed with frontotemporal dementia (bvFTD) so I'm off to ammend my will and complete my bucket list before it's too late.

Comment: Bye @Rick. You'll be missed

Comment: Rick, very sorry to hear that. Hope the diagnosis turns out to be false alarm (or even better, that the post is fake).

Comment: Go out and enjoy the world! And thank you for reminding us that there are any things more important than internet forums!

Comment: As a note: Rick's account was deactivated on the night of September 18 to September 19, 2023. We will miss him.

Comment: @Trish that I presume by himself?

Comment: @Seekinganswers only staff can tell that, but that's when the "user was removed" event happened

Answer (score 13):

Rick, what awful news to receive indeed! I heartily second @IñakiViggers sentiments and wish you a full and speedy recovery. We shall certainly pray and hope that the diagnosis is wrong but in any event I will miss you as one of my favourite if not my single favourite user(s) on the whole site seemingly never driven by ego or indeed anything but an unceasing and totally genuine desire to help people find the information they’re looking for. Some may perhaps rival you in their frequency of densely interesting posts but I reckon none very well may in your honourable, easy going, unfussy and humbly good, seemingly never vindictive nature and so I warmly wish you all the very best in all of your future endeavours in addition to a full and speedy recovery. Take care!